# Updating datatable to multiple tables in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datatable

I have created a method to add data from a datatable to a table in my database via entity framework, however it only allows me to populate one table and I want to populate multiple tables within the one method.

Below is my method adding to the student table and I have commented out the module table because when I add this in no data is transferred to the database. Can someone recommend a way I can populate multiple tables within this method?

Thanks

```
public Boolean ConvertDataTable(DataTable tbl)
    {
        string Feedback = string.Empty;
        ModuleEntities db = new ModuleEntities();
        // iterate over your data table
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {

            student st = new student();
            st.student_no = row.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
            st.surname = row.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
            st.firstname = row.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
            db.students.Add(st);
            //module mod = new module();
            //mod.module_code = row.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
            //mod.name = row.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
            //db.modules.Add(mod);


        }
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            Feedback = "Upload Successful";
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Feedback = "Upload Failed";
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Student Class

```
public partial class student
{
    public student()
    {
        this.submits = new HashSet<submit>();
        this.takes = new HashSet<take>();
        this.lecturers = new HashSet<lecturer>();
    }

    public string student_no { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<submit> submits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<take> takes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<lecturer> lecturers { get; set; }
}
```

Module Class

```
public partial class module
{
    public module()
    {
        this.takes = new HashSet<take>();
        this.lecturers = new HashSet<lecturer>();
    }

    public string module_code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<take> takes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<lecturer> lecturers { get; set; }
}
```

Take Class

```
public partial class take
{
    public string student_no { get; set; }
    public string module_code { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }

    public virtual module module { get; set; }
    public virtual student student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you uncomment that code?  Do you get an exception, does it succeed and that changes are not persisted...  It may also be helpful to post the class structure for those 2 entities.

Comment: Also note it's important to dispose of your DB context (`db` variable in your code) when you're done with it. The usual way to do this is with a using block.

Comment: @drneel when i uncomment the code it does run however no table populates with data, at present the data does populate in the student table. Do you mean to the post the models by class structure?

Comment: Post the classes for: ModuleEntities, Students and Module.  Do neither students or modules persist or just one of the two?

Comment: @drneel ModuleEntities is the name of my database that I am referencing the tables from, it seems that students is the only table I can populate. Is it worth mentioning that I have previously populated my datatable with a CSV file? The three classes I added are what I hope to populate

Comment: try uncommenting your code and running it again, then see the output window for any possible exception.  Sometimes the exceptions are not thrown because of the Debug Exceptions settings.

Comment: Checked the output window and get the following message on a regular occurence: "Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the gist of adding related data to database using Entity Framework:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SchoolDBEntities dataContext = new SchoolDBEntities();
        //Create student object
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.StudentName = "Student 01";
        //Create course objects
        Cours mathCourse = new Cours();
        mathCourse.CourseName = "Math";
        Cours scienceCourse = new Cours();
        scienceCourse.CourseName = "Science";
        //Save courses to student 1
        student1.Courses.Add(mathCourse);
        student1.Courses.Add(scienceCourse);
        //Save related data to database
        //This will automatically populate join table
        //between Students and Courses
        dataContext.Students.Add(student1);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Another illustration:
[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, I have tried your method but I can not directly link student to module (eg student.module.add), is there something I am missing in my model class or is my database set up wrong?

Comment: I noticed in StudentCourses or StudentModule (or the join table) that if I had any other fields in the table except for the primary key fields (like a table id), EF wouldn't generate properly for unknown reason. Also make sure your primary key in join table have both fields as key. And finally, an indicator that EF did it right is that you won't see the join table appear in the EF Relationship diagram. It will be inferred. So, in other words, You'll see Student and Module but you shouldn't see StudentModule class in EF diagram.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have now my tables set up correctly but am still receiving a problem with adding to the database, it all seems to be in place when I add a breakpoint at the  dataContext.Students.Add(student1) stage, Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: Got this working eventually thanks, found out I was adding in the module primary key on multiple occasions which was failing